# set only $gc using session_set_save_handler

Tags: php, session

I would like to my custom gc function for session. I looked up 'session_set_save_handler', but it looks like I have to all the other handlers (open,read,write..) as well.

How can I set only gc handler?

Comment: Why would you want to only set a custom garbage collector? What’s wrong with the garbage collector of PHP’s default session handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can set only one of those handlers : you either let PHP deal with sessions, or you set your own systems, but, generally speaking, you won't mix your own system into parts of PHP's one.